# Confusion between CMake preset fields and cache variables

Tags: cmake, cmake-presets

There is pretty new but cool feature in CMake: [presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake-presets.7.html)

I am confused with some of the possible values of preset: `toolchainFile` and `installDir`. This values could be set using simple cache variables, using `cacheVariables` entries (strictly `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`).

There is only a mention about `toolchainFile` in documentation, that states:

> This field takes precedence over any CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE value.

This does not resolves my confusion. The question is: Which method should I use and what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] and what is the difference?

The docs explain the difference:

> > If a relative path is specified, it is calculated relative to the build directory, and if not found, relative to the source directory.

The cache variable is expected to be an *absolute* path (typically computed from `${sourceDir}`).

> The question is: Which method should I use[?]

You should probably use the more specific option. It's a bit clearer and marginally less typing. Not a huge deal either way.